# How to parse local time without a date with moment?

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs, moment-timezone

Input `8:30 PM` with the local date of May 12th 2020 while UTC date already May 13th 2020

Desired Output `2020-05-12 20:30:00`

Actual Output `2020-05-13 20:30:00`

---

Tried 3 things:

`result = moment('8:30 PM', 'h:mm A').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');`

`result = moment.tz('8:30 PM', 'h:mm A', 'America/New_York').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');`

```
moment.tz.setDefault('America/New_York');
result = moment.tz('8:30 PM', 'h:mm A', 'America/New_York').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
```

Comment: I don't get the same result, '8:30 PM' is parsed as local not UTC.

Comment: @RobG - my mistake, you are right... However - if I change my timezone, how can I set moment to still be in "America/New_York"?

Comment: after checking I'm fairly sure now there's actually an issue with the timezone plugin.  it always uses the forward date.  `moment.tz('10:30 PM', 'h:mm A', moment.tz.guess()).format('YYYY-MM-DD')` with any time always gives the forward date, while moment() doesn't.  Although OP, you really shouldn't be doing this, because if you pass it to another computer in that form it becomes ambiguous without a date.  ie: even though there's a problem with .tz here, there isn't a valid use case for using it this way anyways

Comment: It seems that when you set the timezone and parse a time, moment.tz uses the current UTC date for the date part whereas moment.js uses the current local date. I guess you'd rather that moment.tz uses current date in the set timezone. File a bug if you like but as far as I know the moment.js team has turned its attention to Luxon and moment.js is in maintenance mode, so if not "works as designed" then likely "won't fix". :-/

Answer (score 1):

As user120242 says it seems that moment.tz uses the current UTC date when creating a date from a time. If you want to use the current date in the target timezone, a kludge is to create a string for the date, tack on your time string then parse that, e.g.

```js
moment.tz.setDefault('America/New_York');

let timeString    = '8:30 PM';
let inputFormat   = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm A'
let dateFormat    = 'YYYY-MM-DD';
let displayFormat = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss ZZ';

// Current date in New York
let now = moment();
// Create a timestamp for required time
let nyString = now.format(dateFormat) + ' ' + timeString;
// Create a date for 8:30 in New York
let then = moment(nyString, inputFormat);

console.log('Now in New York    : ' + now.format(displayFormat));
console.log(timeString + ' in New York: ' + then.format(displayFormat));
console.log('Sans kludge in NY  : ' + moment(timeString, 'HH:mm A').format(displayFormat));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.25.3/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.28/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
```

To see it work you need to set your clock so New York is a different date to UTC.

Answer (score 0):

When running the second piece of code tried there, the console contains an error.

> Moment Timezone has no data for America/New_York. See http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-loading/.

If you haven't yet loaded a set of time zones into moment, it wont have data to use for the parsing. Check that you've loaded the time zone data into moment before trying to run any time zone related functions. If you are unsure of how to load the data into moment, check the part of the docs listed in the error message, [here](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-loading/).

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify what problem you are actually solving;
OP, you shouldn't do this anyways, because the time becomes ambiguous if it is sent to another computer.  If the time is currently 12AM or 11:59PM, with people in different time zones, the time you send becomes ambiguous.
If you really still must do it this way, you will have to set the date on the result, or set hours and minutes manually after calculating the "desired" date, to always calculate it to be a time within the last 24 hours.

Yes, there is an issue with the timezone plugin.  In actuality moment() also misbehaves when it's a time before now.  But I can't think of a valid use case for using it the way you are trying to use it, and how it should behave isn't well defined anymore with how you're using it.

Proof of the issue:

```js
moment.tz.setDefault('America/New_York');
result = moment.tz('8:30 PM', 'h:mm A', 'America/New_York').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');

// set your clock to a time when UTC date will be tomorrow (or yesterday) to see the problem
console.log([result,
moment('12:01AM', 'h:mm A').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'),
moment.tz('12:01 AM', 'h:mm A', moment.tz.guess()).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'),
moment('11:59PM', 'h:mm A').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'),
moment.tz('11:59 PM', 'h:mm A', moment.tz.guess()).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')].join('\n')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.25.3/moment-with-locales.min.js" integrity="sha256-8d6kI5cQEwofkZmaPTRbKgyD70GN5mDpTYNP9YWhTlI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.28/moment-timezone-with-data.js" integrity="sha256-O1PdKrSbpAYWSBteb7yX/CMmHhu3US31mtCbsryGwaY=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I think it's a valid thing to do. By setting the timezone first, it's not ambiguous. E.g. creating a date for 08:00 in New York should create a date for that time using the current date in New York, not the UTC or local date. That makes the outcome consistent regardless of the host settings (provided the clock is set correctly of course).