# How to subtract or add GMT number from new Date in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have IST date and time - Thu Oct 01 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), i need to convert that date time based on users browser timezone.
So, if i can Subtract or Addition GMT value from my datetime, i can get the correct date time.
Please help.

```
        var newdate = $(this).data("systemdate");
        var format = $(this).data("format");

        var timezone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
        var tm_short = moment.tz(newdate, timezone).format('z');

        var datecoverted = new Date(newdate+" GMT+0530")

        var result = moment(datecoverted).format(format);
```

I have tried with above code, it's working fine in chrome. but it's showing invalid date in Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We are unable to help if you don't show us the code that is causing the problem. Please edit your question to include the *relevant* code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you have tried already to fix the issue so that we can help.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question. Can you give us the exact error you are getting in Firefox?

Comment: it's showing 'Invalid date'

Comment: actually Mozilla not supporting 'datecoverted' variable in my code.

Comment: why aren't you using moment.tz?

Comment: actually, no need for now.

Comment: firstly i tried with moment js. but it's not giving exact time...

Comment: what does the systemdate string look like?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Note: **"Support for RFC 2822 format strings is by convention only."** [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#Syntax)  (RFC2822 is the string format at the start of OP's question)
And thus the conclusion can be made, that the use of the language "implementation dependent" everywhere in the specs is deliberately ambiguous, deferring to browser developers choices, but maintaining that it is not normative.
You can probably get away with using it, like object map key order can be used, but it is important to make the distinction that it is *not by spec* and eg moment.js chose to reject it most likely for this very reason.

OP tried to build his own ISO date string, which FF could not read, because he was using the wrong suffix.  He probably could have gotten by with validating his string and using:
`datestring +='+05:30'`
instead of GMT+05:30 which makes the ISO string invalid.

Note for future readers.  moment.js does have some issues and is not necessarily the best choice for everything related to Dates.  You can most of the time get by with just normal Dates and using timestamp math, and you don't really need to bring in moment.js as a dependency.

However, as is shown in this thread, parsing of Dates can be problematic and allowing the built-in Date to parse your dates can cause unexpected results, especially because different platforms can give different results.  Make sure you are fully aware of the subtle differences between platforms.
(Things like time zone differences, leap years, month day differences, string formatting (which is now mostly good enough with Intl.DateTimeFormat) are a few other reasons you should reach for a date library.  Although moment(tz) does have [subtle edge case bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61764708/how-to-parse-local-time-without-a-date-with-moment/61765358#61765358) even in that regard.)

The date given at the top in the question is similar to the (string display representation) for Date format ratified in ES2015.  Unfortunately, the month and day are not in the same order as the ratified standard, which contributed to additional problems when communicating with OP.

Using moment, moment.tz, and [custom format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

```js
//var newdate = $(this).data("systemdate");
//var format = $(this).data("format");

// shim newdate, format values
newdate=`Thu Oct 01 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`
format = `ddd MMM DD YYYY hh:mm:ss ZZ`

var timezone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
// other ways to get timezone.  use the one that gets the right results:
t=new Date().getTimezoneOffset()/60
var timezone2 = `+${`${t|0}`.padStart(2,'0')}:${`${(t-(t|0))*60}`.padStart(2,'0')}` 

console.log(moment.tz.guess(), timezone, timezone2)

// example custom format string using strict mode and isValid() for first example:
var result = moment(newdate.replace(/ \(.*\)/,''),'ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss [GMT]Z', true)
if (result.isValid())
 result = result.tz(timezone).format(format)
else; //didn't match, continue to try to parse date string with other methods here

console.log(result);

newdate=`2020-11-01 05:30:00`

// this works, but is not recommended:
// should use strict mode to make sure you recognize the format
// and you want to force time zone parsing in your desired time zone
var result = moment.tz(newdate, 'Asia/Calcutta').tz(timezone).format(format);
console.log(result);

// notice 3rd parameter is true for strict mode.  reject dates that don't match
var result = moment.tz(newdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss', true, 'Asia/Calcutta')
if (result.isValid())
 result = result.tz(timezone).format(format)
else; // try to fallback to parsing date other ways
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.25.3/moment-with-locales.min.js" integrity="sha256-8d6kI5cQEwofkZmaPTRbKgyD70GN5mDpTYNP9YWhTlI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.28/moment-timezone-with-data.js" integrity="sha256-O1PdKrSbpAYWSBteb7yX/CMmHhu3US31mtCbsryGwaY=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Invalid Date

Object { _isAMomentObject: true, _i: "Thu Oct 01 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)", _f: "ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss Z", _tzm: 330, _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, _locale: {…}, _a: (7) […], _d: Date Thu Oct 01 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), _isValid: true, … }
 Thu Oct 01 2020 05:30:00 +0530

Comment: will it always be (India Standard... )?  I've updated it, and chosen to discard the parens timezone if found

Comment: yes it will be Indian standard time always. and i tried with updated code... on chrome it's working. on the time is not changing... it's showing  the same datetime Thu Oct 01 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530

Comment: {…}
​
_a: Array(7) [ 2020, 9, 1, … ]
​
_d: Date Thu Oct 01 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
​
_f: "ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss [GMT]Z"
​
_i: "Thu Oct 01 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530"
​
_isAMomentObject: true
​
_isUTC: false
​
_isValid: true
​
_locale: Object { _calendar: {…}, _longDateFormat: {…}, _invalidDate: "Invalid date", … }
​
_pf: Object { empty: false, overflow: -1, charsLeftOver: 0, … }
​
_tzm: 330
​
_z: null
​
<prototype>: Object { add: qt(e, t), calendar: calendar(e, t), clone: clone(), … }
 Thu Oct 01 2020 05:30:00 +0530

Comment: I'm using `Thu Oct 01 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` as the date string for the model to parse on.  Is that the actual format of the date time you are using?  You are using a non-standard date string format, so it needs to be specially handled.

Comment: i have tested with this same date time that you used 'Thu Oct 01 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)' and i have changed my time zone to +05:00, on chrome it showing Thu Oct 01 2020 05:00:00 GMT+0500. but in Mozilla it's showing 'Thu Oct 01 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530'

Comment: try the new code?  seems like firefox is reporting the wrong time zone?

Comment: also it is important to note, the string I'm using is a non-standard time string that I got from your question

Comment: if my time format be '2020-11-01 05:30:00' instead of 'Thu Oct 01 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` what changes i need to do?

Comment: or how to convert '2020-11-01 05:30:00' to 'Thu Oct 01 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)' this format.

Comment: so what I'm understanding is that if no time zone is present, you want it to use zone +0530?  do you want it to check for 2020-11-01 05:30:00 format, and use that timezone if it is found?  What you have there is standard iso time, but without timezone

Comment: correct. my time format is now '2020-11-01 05:30:00' that's +0530 time. so i have to set that for your code. thanks.

Comment: So I've created an update.  Uses "Asia/Calcutta", which is +05:30, as the timezone to parse it in.  I recommend using "strict" parsing mode, and checking isValid(), and if it isn't valid fall back to other parsing methods.

Comment: For me this returns "Wed Jan 01 2020 10:00:00 +1000". What is the point of the first assignment to *newDate* when it is immediately replaced by the assignment of a different value? The tokens for parsing are wrong,

Comment: @RobG It was for accounting for the data he was using.  He didn't provide the actual date string he was using, so I used the one in the question in the first implementation.  You can see the commented out example of custom date parsing for just that kind of date string.  I've left it in for the possibility someone needs that kind of complex date string parsing and needed an example.  I thought this example would be of value to future reads so I left it in.

Comment: @RobG I think I must have accidentally broken the code while editing back in the custom parsing for the first string back in.  Didn't notice that the date was coming back wrong.  Found the error, the parsing string has the wrong month parsing on it.

Comment: The reason it wasn't noticed before, was because he's using standard iso dates, so the custom formatting was actually unnecessary in this case, as long as he didn't try to tack on the invalid formatted time zone.  'Asia/Calcutta' would sufficiently fix the time zone problem for him in the original code, had he not tried to concatenate GMT+05:30

Answer (score 0):

Timestamps in the format Thu Oct 01 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) are one of only two that are reliably parsed by the built–in parser, so you can pass them directly to the Date constructor:

```
let d = new Date('Thu Oct 01 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)');
```

If the timestamp is generated on the client system, then the system timezone offset will be used by default:

```
d.toString(); // e.g. Thu Oct 01 2020 09:00:00 GMT+0900 (WIT)
```

So there is no need for a library or any messing around with timezones.

If you *really* want to use a library, then you can do the same thing in moment.js using the following:

```js
// Timestamp to parse
let s = 'Thu Oct 01 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)';

// POJS
console.log(new Date(s).toString());

// With moment.js
let format = 'ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss ZZ';
console.log(moment(s, format).format(format));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.26.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You didn't read the comments.  He's trying to convert an ISO date time without proper timezone information into local time, and it was breaking in Firefox, because Date.parse (and constructor) under Firefox is more restrictive and can't parse weird date strings as well.  Your code would have still failed to work for him, and additionally doesn't do the time zone conversion that he wanted.  If you want to see and understand the reasoning you can try to read the code I wrote and the comments discussing the problem with OP.

Comment: If you want to write a version without moment for him you can use this string: "2020-11-01 05:30:00".  @RobG try to feed the string you claim to be reliably parsed to moment.js and see the warning that flashes.  It is _not_ recommended that you use strings in that format fed to Date.parse, as others with more experience than either of us have deemed that kind of parsing unreliable across platforms.

Comment: If you can find documentation from someone reliable that can support the claim that the format you have claimed is safe and reliably parsed by Date across platforms, please do post it, as I would like to know as well.

Comment: @user120242—[*ECMA-262*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-date.parse) is not hard to find: "*The \[Date.parse\] function first attempts to parse the String according to the format described in Date Time String Format ([20.3.1.15](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-date-time-string-format))…*". The warning you see from moment.js is not normative.

Comment: You are correct, thanks.  Deciphered and understood the specs; I wasn't reading the specs correctly.  toString and implementation specific reference is just to allow for safely discardable (Timezone Name) suffix, and to avoid promising toString as a serialized format when toJSON->toISOString exists.  But `Date.parse` is still required to be able to parse toString output.

Comment: Found that you were actually _not_ correct, and my original interpretation of it being ambiguously referred to as implementation dependent was actually correct.  They were purposely being ambiguous, because it is by [convention](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#Syntax) only, not because it is standards compliant.  **"Support for RFC 2822 format strings is by convention only."**  I was trying too hard to justify the design of the specs and instead read too far into it.

Comment: So if even MDN leaves warnings repeatedly that Date string parsing is strongly discouraged, and a major library like moment.js chooses to reject this format, I think it can be safely said that the consensus is that datetime string parsing, and especially RFC 2822 as used in this post, is actually the non-normative choice.  Modern browser vendors just happen to support it for compatibility reasons, but it is not a trivially detectable difference if it is not supported.  And furthermore they are not the only major bodies to discourage datetime string parsing.

Comment: @user120242—MDN is a public wiki to which anyone can contribute, it's not authoritative. I'm aware of its warnings about the built–in parser—I'm partially responsible for them. Since EMCA-262 Edition 5 (aka ES5) in 2011, browsers have been required to parse strings of the format  YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ, at the time only IE8 was non–compliant. As of ECMAScript 2016, they were also required to parse the string generated by their *toString* and *toUTCString* methods. As of ECMAScript 2018, the format of *toString* has been standardised. So browsers should (and do) correctly parse them.

Comment: @user120242—the reference to RFC 2822 on the MDN Date constructor page is a red herring, it's not referenced on the [Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) page (which is where information on parsing should be). The format specified by ECMA-262 for [*toString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-date.prototype.tostring) is not RFC 2822 compliant (though it's very close).